# How to detect heterogeneous CPU topologies on Linux?

Tags: linux, cpu-cores, cpuid

Many recent CPUs out there--Alder Lake from Intel and many big.LITTLE designs from ARM--have heterogeneous CPU topologies: some cores are faster than others.  There exists good ways to detect such CPUs on Windows and macOS, but Linux/Android seems lacking.

On x86, there is a CPUID bit: leaf 7 page 0 EDX bit 15.  But ARM's CPUID equivalent is privileged, so OS help is required.

Is there a good way on Linux to detect this?

For posterity:

- On Windows, use `GetLogicalProcessorInformationEx` to enumerate packages and cores, then look for `.Processor.EfficiencyClass` being different values among cores (queries using `RelationProcessorCore`).
- On macOS, use `sysctlbyname` on `hw.nperflevels` and check whether it exists and its value is greater than `1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think (not that I've ever used the programming interface) that you're after [libhwloc's cpuset](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/libhwloc-doc/hwloc_topology_get_online_cpuset.3.en.html).

From `aptitude show hwloc`:

> Description: Hierarchical view of the machine - utilities  Hardware
> Locality (hwloc) provides a portable abstraction (across OS, versions,
> architectures, ...) of the  hierarchical topology of modern
> architectures. It primarily aims at helping high-performance computing
> applications  with gathering information about the hardware so as to
> exploit it accordingly and efficiently.
>
> hwloc provides a hierarchical view of the machine, NUMA memory nodes,
> sockets, shared caches, cores and simultaneous  multithreading. It
> also gathers various attributes such as cache and memory information.
>
> hwloc supports old kernels not having sysfs topology information,
> with knowledge of cpusets, offline cpus, and  Kerrighed support
>
> This package contains utilities to show the topology of the machine
> (lstopo and hwloc-ls), manipulate cpu masks  (hwloc-calc), and bind
> processes (hwloc-bind). Homepage:
> https://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/